# Django - display an error message when form is invalid with "CreateView"

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Here is my simplified "ProjectCreate" ClassBasedView :

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name', 'creation_date', 'price']


class ProjectCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm
    success_message = "Project successfully created"
    success_url = "project-list"

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(ProjectCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields.pop('creation_date')
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.instance.name == "not_valid_name":
            return super().form_invalid(form)
        form.instance.last_editor = self.request.user
        form.instance.last_modification_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I want to create the project only if the name isn't "not_valid_name"

If the name is "not_valid_name", i want to display an error message (saying that the name isn't valid), and bring back the user to the 'project create' page

If you need any additional informations to understand my problem, don't hesitate to ask me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this at different levels:

- at the `Form` level: [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/validation/) is the link to the corresponding page in the documentation. In short, use the `clean` method of the field `name`, the following code should be easy to understand:

```py
from django import forms
from ??? import Project

class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # I assume you already have some code here
    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data.get("name")
        if name in ["invalid_name_1", "invalid_name_2"]: # etc.
            raise ValidationError("Forbidden value for this field.")
        return name

    class Meta(forms.ModelForm.Meta):
        model = Project
```

With this code (and a few lines more in the template), this is what the client will see:
[image: example_bootstrap5]

- at the `Model` level: you could use a custom validator. Check [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/validators/) for further information, it's quite well written.
- at the `View` level, as you were trying to do, there should be a way, but I think it's not the best solution because it's cleaner to keep the validation logic in the form & model fields. A reason for that, for instance, is that you might be willing to keep the same constraint in the `admin` app when editing your `Project` instances. Here's a hint if you prefer that alternative: [this page](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.1/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/) lists all available & useful methods in a `CreateView`.